# Communicating with BLE using Python in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using **Mac OS X Yosemite** and I need to commmunicate with a **Bluetooth Low Energy** board. I would like to use **Python** but I cannot find any libraries that support Bluetooth 4.0.

Does anyone have a code snippet to communicate or a specific library?

Comment: The little bit of code I've seen interacts with the Linux kernel...  I'm not sure if any of that is transferable to OS X.  You should look to see if there are C libraries available and use the C API to Python to use it.

Comment: I was looking for something similar and ended up settling on the LightBlue app for iOS, which lets you scan for other BLE devices, discover services, and read/write characteristics. Depending on your needs this may serve as a good substitute

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty cool, thanks! Though I still need to be able to program the output to the device. So I decided to try it on Linux and apparently it works pretty much ok with gattlib!